# How to control the current/voltage in resistive wires

Tags: heat, resistive

I'm new to electronics, and I was planning to make a heater to heat up a stainless steel container, and I was wondering if there was a way to control the temperature by controlling the current or voltage? I'm using nichrome wires for the resistive wires. The nichrome wires I'm using are 0.3MM in diameter and 20.10 Ohms/m

Comment: Question says control I/V question says Temperature. Which is it?If it is temperature, heat up, yes, but control needs feedback, some sort of temperature sensor.

Comment: Yes. You can control the temperature if you use a feedback circuit to adjust either voltage or current in response to temperature reading. What is the voltage of the power source? Shock hazard is a concern here. The stainless vessel may become energized at a hazardous voltage depending on how you do this.

Comment: Power is P=I^2*R and P=V^2/R so by varying the voltage across the resistor you can vary the heat. There are many ways to vary the voltage

Answer (score 3):

For a fixed length of wire you can control either voltage or current. Controlling one will control the other by Ohm's Law, \$ V = IR \$ although the resistance will increase as the wire heats up.

Controlling either V or I will adjust power (P) which is measured in watts (W).

To control temperature—to heat to 80°C, for example—requires a temperature sensor wired to a temperature controller and something to switch the current off when setpoint is reached.

The simplest solution is to use a thermostat.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOsIp5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Thermostat and heater wiring. When the thermostat setpoint is exceeded the contact will open and shut off the power.*